# how to use__iter__ to dynamically create objects in python

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, iterator

Ok, so I am trying to print all the car objects... I have 2 questions:

1. Is the way I am implementing `__iter__` acceptable?
2. I am getting the results I want now, but the result is rather ugly... is there a way to format the printing to make it look prettier?

Here's my code:

```
import sqlite3

class Database:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.filename = kwargs.get('filename')

    def __iter__(self):
        car_object = {}
        cursor = self._db.execute('select * from CARS'.format(self._table))
        for row in cursor:
            objectname = str(row['IDENT'])
            car_object[objectname] = Cars(make = row['MAKE'], 
            model = row['MODEL'], disp = row['DISPLACEMENT'], 
            power = row['POWER'], luxury = row['LUXURY'])
            yield dict(row)

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return self._filename

    @filename.setter
    def filename(self, fn):
        self._filename = fn
        self._db = sqlite3.connect(fn)
        self._db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row


class Cars: 
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.variables = kwargs

    def set_Variable(self, k, v):
        self.variables[k] = v

    def get_Variable(self, k):
        return self.variables.get(k, None)

def main():
    db = Database(filename = 'insurance.sqlite')
    print ('IDENT                       MAKE               MODEL                   
    DISPLACEMENT             POWER              LUXURY')
    for item in db:
        print(item['IDENT'], '            ', item['MAKE'], '            ', 
          item['MODEL'],'            ', item['DISPLACEMENT'],
          '            ', item['POWER'],'            ', item['LUXURY'])


if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Comment: your indentation looks to be incorrect. That's not the source of your bug, it's just a formatting issue with the question.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley...it looks fine in eclipse, but this page just makes it look odd.

Comment: nobody is going to be looking at your code in eclipse. Please take the time to format it correctly for the question. The easiest thing might be for you to convert all tabs to spaces before pasting it into the question.

Comment: Bryan, apologies, I have edited it.  Thank you.

Comment: It still looks incorrect. With python you need to be particularly diligent since the amount of indentation defines what block a line of code is in. Your def's need to be indented more than your class statement.

Comment: indentantion should be good now.  I have 2 questions: is the way i am implementing '__iter__' acceptable? 2. i am getting the results i want now, but as you can probably tell, the result is rather ugly...is there a way to format the printing to make it look prettier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to print out the generator itself, you want to print each item returned by the generator.

```
for item in db:
    print(item)
```

Comment: thank  you....do you think it is acceptable to have an '__iter__' like I do above?

Comment: @user2096860 I've never actually used `__iter__` before so I had to look it up. Yes I think you're using it properly, by having a `yield` in the body the function returns a generator which is exactly what you need. I'm not sure why you're both returning the results and saving them internally though.

Comment: Ransomactually,i want to be able to print the car_object[objectname] instances...any ideas?

Comment: @user2096860 you'll need to split into 2 loops then, one that does the `select` to fill your dict and then another to iterate through the dict and return each item.